# How can I count my total upvotes/downvotes on my questions/answers?

Tags: support

I'd like to view the total number of upvotes on my questions, upvotes on my answers, downvotes on my questions, and downvotes on my answers.  Is there any way I can do this without manually counting?

Comment: This information must be retrievable from the Data Explorer, but I'm not knowledgeable enough to construct the right query.

Answer (score 8):

If you check the listing from https://stackoverflow.com/reputation you can see this.

```
1   6681021 (15)
1    507917 (2)
2   6681021 (10)
2    998675 (5)
3    408052 (-2)
8    513337 (-500)
9    455882 (200)
16   406317 (2)
2    474872 [2]
```

The first column is the vote type, the second is the post id and the third is the reputation gained or lost. In the third column, the number within square brackets means that you reached the rep cap limit (reached, so `2    474872 [10]` is also possible).

So you can see that:

- 1 is an acceptance - both from having your answer accepted or accepting an answer to your question
- 2 is an upvote
- 3 is a downvote
- 8 is an offered bounty
- 9 is an earned bounty
- 16 is an approved post or tag wiki edit

Reputation changes from removed posts, manual vote retractions, voting corrections and invalidations, user removals, and any other events that cause your reputation to be recalculated do not show in the view; instead, the overall history is shown as if the relevant original votes never existed.

Comment: But is there a quick way to count all the 3's or 2's?  And I'd like to be able to separate question-votes from answer-votes, if possible.

Comment: @drm65 yes, excel. The value on the left is the #, the value on the right is the score, the value in the middle is the post id. Ergo, upvotes on Q's are +5 (so a (3) and a 15) and upvotes on answers are +10 (so a (2) and a 20) and accepts are +15 (giving (1) and 15). If you can't figure out how to conjure those summations out of Excel ... you might need to find a new career. If I had Excel on this laptop, I would conjure you a spreadsheet, but by Monday I will have forgotten this and lost interest.

Comment: @drm65 Download the `/reputation` page to a file, then run this command in a terminal: `<reputation.html awk '$1=="1" && $3=="(15)" {++a} $1=="2" {++up} $1=="3" && $3=="(-2)" {++down} END {print up " upvotes, " down " downvotes, " a " accepted answers"}'` (on Windows, you'll need to install a set of unix-like command-line tools such as Cygwin).

Comment: @Gilles: I'm sorry, but I'm not a programmer.  I don't understand a thing you wrote.

Comment: Now that question upvotes also yield 10 rep you can no longer distinguish them from answer upvotes

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's anywhere in the main UI that shows that information. Your profile page shows the number of votes you've *cast*, but not the number you've received. I guess the idea here is that your reputation reflects that, albeit in a modified way.

You can get the raw numbers by doing a query on the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) (linked as "data" in the footer of the SE sites). Note that it will be current as of the last monthly dump, not up-to-the-minute.

Comment: Something like this shows total answer upvotes received for user 2303, http://data.stackexchange.com/english/q/105684/

Answer (score 1):

The following [SEDE Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/english/query/1190618/how-can-i-count-my-total-upvotes-downvotes-on-my-questions-answers?UserId=10041) does that for you.

The first row will show you overall totals followed by the per post counts. Currently the order is on creationdate of the post. You can fork the query to change that to any of the the other columns or preferred sort expression.

```sql
; with vote_stats as
(
select concat('site://q/', p.id, '|', q.title) as [Post]
     , p.creationdate
     , (case when p.posttypeid = 1 then 'Question' else 'Answer' end) [Q or A] 
     , sum(case when votetypeid = 1 then 1 else 0 end) accept
     , sum(case when votetypeid = 2 then 1 else 0 end) upvote
     , sum(case when votetypeid = 3 then 1 else 0 end) downvote 
from posts p
inner join posts q on q.id = coalesce(p.parentid, p.id)
inner join votes v on v.postid = p.id
where p.owneruserid = ##userid?10041##
and v.votetypeid in (1,2,3)
and p.posttypeid in (1,2)
group by p.id
       , q.title
       , p.creationdate
       , p.posttypeid 
)

select concat('site://users/', ##userid?10041##, '?tab=reputation','|user reputation') [Link]
     , null creationdate
     , 'Total' [Q or A]
     , sum(accept) accept
     , sum(upvote) upvote
     , sum(downvote) downvote
from vote_stats
union
select *
from vote_stats
order by [Q or A] desc
       , creationdate desc
```

When run today this will be your result on ELU.se:

[image: sede query result]

SEDE is updated once a week, on Sunday.
Give a big shout-out to [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio) for the awesome [SEDE Tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) she wrote.
Say "Hi" in [SEDE chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede).